# python-pptx with matplotlib fix image resolution

Tags: matplotlib, python-pptx

i am trying to generate  a graph using matplotlib and save it to python-pptx . everything is working fine but the image resolution is low when imported to pptx.( i am just saving to memory using `StringIO` then using `add_picture()` in pptx to add image)

when i do :

```
some_image_in_memory = StringIO()
plt.savefig(some_image_in_memory)
```

it works fine but give low res image but when i do :

```
plt.savefig(some_image_in_memory, format='svg')
```

i get error:

```
cannot identify image file <StringIO.StringIO INstamce at ..>
```

is this even correct? svg should maintain resolution but i cant read this in pptx.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by setting `dpi` value to `savefig()`:
ex

```
plt.savefig(some_image_stream_in_memory, dpi=1200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, PowerPoint does not directly support the SVG format (I've heard it's a turf issue between MS and Adobe). I expect that explains the error you're getting when you save with `format=svg`.

Other folks seem to have good luck with the PNG format from matplotlib. I kind of suppose that's the default image format, but might be worth a check.

The other thing that occurs to me is I don't see anywhere you have specified the size of the graph to be saved from matplotlib. If it is getting saved as a small image and then getting scaled significantly larger when displaying it in PowerPoint, this will produce a "grainy" appearance.

Comment: Starting with office 2019, SVG images are supported. So is export to SVG.

Comment: Support for SVG is still challenging because PowerPoint stores a Windows Meta File (WMF) format image as well, as a fallback for prior versions of PowerPoint, and there are no resources I know of in Python to reliably generate a WMF file from an SVG. So limited support could perhaps be added, but your SVG images would only appear for folks with the very latest PowerPoint, and in general, folks seem to lag behind in MS Office versions; there's still plenty of 2007 and 2013 out there for example.